# Mongodb aggregate $group and count for date ranges

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like these:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc80389c723e046f504b5a9"),
    "adddress" : "string",
    "checkIn" : "2019-04-30T08:12:57.909Z"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc995f5a6f3eb7c483b019f"),
    "adddress" : "string",
    "checkIn" : "2019-05-01T12:49:57.561Z"
}
```

I have tried aggrgation like this:

```
     var start = new Date("2019-04-30T08:12:57.909Z");
        var end = new Date("2019-05-01T12:49:57.561Z");
        var pipeline = [
        {
            $match: {
                checkIn: {
                    $gte: start,
                    $lte: end
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    year: {
                        $year: "$checkIn"
                    },
                    month: {
                        $month: "$checkIn"
                    },
                    day: {
                        $dayOfYear: "$checkIn"
                    }
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }];
```

db.collections.aggregate(pipeline).toArray()

Is it possible to count them by checkIn date and get result like this:

```
    "_id": [{
        "checkIn": "2019-03-15T00:00:00Z",
        "count": 4
    }, {
        "checkIn": "2019-04-30T00:00:00Z",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "checkIn": "2019-05-10T00:00:00Z",
        "count": 1
    }],
```

Comment: Do you want group them by only date(day,month,year) or you want time also.?

Comment: only group them by date in range

Comment: please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: I have tested this query and its working.

```js
db.sample.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$checkIn"
        }
      }
    }
  },{
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: start,
        $lte: end
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateString: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dateString",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: thnks its working but I want it for date range like                                                          $match: {
                checkIn: {
                    $gte: start,
                    $lte: end
                }
            }

Comment: Since this solution fulfills all the requirements of your question , but you accepted the incorrect solution. please tell me the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

```
The result is shown the total number of the day.

{$project: {
  checkIn: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$checkIn' } }
}},
{$group: {
  _id: '$checkIn',
  checkIn: {$first: '$checkIn'},
  count: {$sum: 1}
}},
{$sort: {checkIn: 1}}
```

Comment: I want to group them by date(day,month,year) and date is startdate and enddate

Comment: You can group multiple fields. For example "_id": {
            "startDate": "$startDate",
            "endDate": "$endDate"
        },

Comment: This query throws error : `"can't convert from BSON type string to Date"`.

Comment: Please don't accept wrong/buggy answers because this will misguide others viewers.